Invoke-WebRequest returns empty object
I am writing a script using Visual Studio Code that will download an EXE and then install it. I have been working on this for a few hours each day for a couple of days building out the code to do what I require, testing in Code as I go along.
The Invoke-WebRequest line downloads the file everytime (it goes to a temp folder which is deleted at the end of the script run). Just after the Invoke-WebRequest line I tested for the Status Code of $result and would only proceed if it was 200.
All of a sudden, $result has started being null. So I test for the Status Code but it skips the if block because there is no Status Code in $result. I started testing in new PowerShell terminals and I get the same. PowerShell 5 or 7, it makes no difference.
The code I am now testing with is this:
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/download/v25.0.2/draw.io-25.0.2-windows-installer.exe -OutFile 'D:\test.exe'

Write-Host $result.StatusCode

What am I not seeing that is causing this to behave in this way?
I tried disabling any caching by adding -Headers @{"Cache-Control"="no-cache"} to the command, same result.
I tried on another machine, same.
I tried putting a try .. catch block around the code to see I was missing an error, but nothing.

In short: As explained in the duplicate that  @zett42 found, when you use -OutFile with  Invoke-WebRequest, it produces no output by default. To get a [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject] instance as output, whose .StatusCode property you can query, you must add the -PassThru switch.
